# How to upload data to web server through arduino gprs module

Tags: google-maps, tcp, gps, arduino, gprs

I have successfully worked out for 2 days and made a program for my arduino to reply me it's gps location coordinates to my mobile phone whenever I send a command to it through sms, but now I want to track it by gprs using 2g network so that I can track it 24x7,But I have no idea how to do this,I saw few tutorials that uses xively.com to graph the incoming data,but in this case my arduino will be transmitting gps coordinates ,so is there any easy way to store these values and directly locate them using google maps?Thanks in advance,please help me.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you send two strings to xively: one with your lattitude coordinates and one with your longitude.  Then, I would recommend that you fetch that data using the google maps api.